# Facing issue with AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android

I am facing the following issue.

```
String[] pkg_id = new String[]{package_id};

     Log.d("pkg_id","=>"+Arrays.toString(pkg_id));
HashMap<String,String> data_pkg_act = new HashMap<>();
for(int k=0;k<pk_id.length;k++)
{
    Log.d("pkg_id","==>"+package_id);
    //Here am getting pkg_id==>1 and pkg_id==> 2 

    try {

        data_pkg_act.put("package_id", package_id);
        new GetPackageDetails(data_pkg_act).execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

HashMap is overriding the 1st value with 2nd I wanted to make a call twice based on package_id. AsyncTask calling twice but with package id 2 am not able to call it for package id 1

Comment: what??? where do you use asynctask in your code???

Comment: @just  here  ....new GetPackageDetails(data_pkg_act).execute().get();

Comment: oh, thx at first i didn't saw it

Answer (score 0):

this is just because, **HashMap** can not have same keys twice. as it works by **key, value** pair. you will need to use separate keys for both entries to make it work.

Comment: Maps in general, not specifically HashMap

Answer (score 0):

> you are using same key 'package_id' for two different package ids

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, can  I implement by pausing fist insertion for some time? And after getting the response of first then make the second call?

Comment: why you don't want to use different key ?